# Installing Oracle database 11g on Window fails

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, window, installation

I got in really stupid situation.
First I am a newbie at Oracle and my English is dumb, I'm trying to install Oracle based on some available tutorial on Google. Exactly this one :

http://allaboutobiee.blogspot.com/2013/09/step-by-step-installation-of-oracle-11g.html

But I was stuck at top 5 as the installing window suddenly disappear with no clues or errors occurred. I started searching on google for solution and I found this answer seems to work. But the problem is I dont know HOW TO APPLY this answer :

"I was having a similar problem (mentioned in another thread I'm still looking for to respond), but it would fail (without notice) when selecting "desktop class" (step 3). We found that there was a problem with the included javaw.exe file, so used the following start line in the command line (from wherever setup.exe is located):

setup -jreLoc c:\PROGRA~1\java\jdk1.6.0_25

(Modify to reflect the location of an alternate JRE, like the one I used above.)

Hopefully this helps. If not, good luck!"

First I tried to turn on my cmd and type this :  "setup -jreLoc c:\PROGRA~1\java\jdk1.6.0_25"

it shown up this message : "Setup is not recognized as an internal or external command,,....."

Can you guys help me, as a newbie, solve my problem ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below steps:

1. Download oracle 11g from oracle site
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html#database

   Files details

   - `win64_11gR2_database_1of2` approx size - 2.12 GB
   - `win64_11gR2_database_2of2` approx size - 948 MG
2. Copy the database folder from `win64_11gR2_database_2of2` and paste it in   `win64_11gR2_database_1of2`.
3. Run the *setup.exe* from `win64_11gR2_database_1of2` folder.

Good Luck!